# methods that give error

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, using

a developer has left the company and left me with his code.
it was working fine

but when I copied the code into my computer, I started getting all sort of errors

There are methods that are used that do not have any definition anywhere, not even google.

Methods are : **get_Routes(), get_Formatters(), get_XmlFormatter(), get_SupportedMediaTypes()**

does anyone know where to define or get these methods from?
do I need to import any library?

this is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace IntMan.WebAPI.App_Start
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            CorsHttpConfigurationExtensions.EnableCors(config);
            HttpConfigurationExtensions.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(config);
            HttpRouteCollectionExtensions.MapHttpRoute(config.get_Routes(), "DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
            MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaTypeHeaderValue = config.get_Formatters().get_XmlFormatter().get_SupportedMediaTypes().FirstOrDefault<MediaTypeHeaderValue>((MediaTypeHeaderValue t) => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
            config.get_Formatters().get_XmlFormatter().get_SupportedMediaTypes().Remove(mediaTypeHeaderValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), or [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com).

Comment: A quick search at MSDN for `MediaTypeHeaderValue` [found a result for me](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.mediatypeheadervalue(v=vs.118).aspx). Seems you need to learn to search better. The first location to search for WIndows-related classes is Google; the second is MSDN (MicroSoft Developers Network). You should try searching there for other parts of the code that are problematic; pay attention to the supported platforms and .Net versions.

Comment: @KenWhite This is not the same method. the method that I want is get_SupportedMediaTypes it has get_ in the beginig the one in the MSDN is MediaTypeHeaderValue

Comment: @KenWhite I have been searching for 2 days. and still cant find it.. I found these methods Formatters, XmlFormatter and SupportedMediaTypes.. all without get_ in the begining

Comment: Those methods are likely custom extension methods - since they clearly violate standard C# naming conventions. Looks more like a java developer wrote them. Have you tried a text search for those methods?

Comment: @GrantWinney yes, these methods do not exist anywhere!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed that this method start with get_

Here is right answer.

Just find "this HttpConfiguration" on entire solution.

You can find extension method named start with "get_"

If this solution not work.. find "this IDisposable" on entire solution.

because HttpConfiguration class is implement of IDisposable

Comment: config is defined as HttpConfiguration. the methods that this class has are without the get_ in the begining

Comment: You've posted a link to the documentation which clearly does *not* expose those methods. So, how is this an answer?